# $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $C^0. f(x,0)=0 \Rightarrow \exists r>0$ such that $|f(x,y)|<\frac{1}{4}$ in $(x,y)\in[0,1]\times[-r,r]$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continue and with $f(x,0)=0$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that there is $r>0$ such that $|f(x,y)|<\frac{1}{4}$ for each $(x,y)\in[0,1]\times[-r,r]$.

My attempt:

Using the continuity, we have that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$ exists $\delta>0$ such that 
$$
(x,y)\in B_\delta(x)\Rightarrow f(x,y)\in B_{\frac{1}{4}}(f(x))=B_{\frac{1}{4}}(0)
$$
(because $f(x,0)=0$)

My problem is how to find the $r$. First I thought test all $x\in[0,1]$ delta's. But this is a infinity number of points. So I try use the fact that $[0,1]$ is a compact, but I don't know how to catch a cover that help-me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well $[0,1] \times \{0\}$ is compact. It is covered by open circles on which $f$ has value less than a quarter since by continuity it is less than a quarter on a neighbourhood of each point.

Take a finite sub-cover. This will contain the set you want. (there is a little work to show at this point but it's elementary geometry.)